# csv import from excel into phpmyadmin missing data

Tags: sql, excel, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to upload data from an excel spreadsheet into a sql server run through a university phpmyadmin. I have been able to upload other files successfully. However, when I upload one particular file with 3 columns and 20 rows, it instead uploads the 3 columns and only data for the 3 rows. I have been advised to tick the box that says "replace existing data" and have selected left "columns enclosed with" blank. 
This is the data I was hoping to upload:

```
FlyCrew01   Yes 1
FlyCrew02   Yes 2
FlyCrew03   No  3
FlyCrew04   Yes 4
FlyCrew05   No  5
FlyCrew06   Yes 6
FlyCrew07   Yes 7
FlyCrew08   Yes 8
FlyCrew09   Yes 9
FlyCrew10   Yes 10
FlyCrew11   Yes 11
FlyCrew12   Yes 12
FlyCrew13   Yes 13
FlyCrew14   Yes 14
FlyCrew15   Yes 15
FlyCrew16   Yes 16
FlyCrew17   Yes 17
FlyCrew18   Yes 18
FlyCrew19   Yes 19
FlyCrew20   Yes 20
```

The end result after uploading is this however:

```
Full texts  
Crew_ID Ascending
Available
Licence_Number

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
FlyCrew0
Yes
9

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
FlyCrew1
Yes
19

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
FlyCrew2
Yes
20
```

As you can see, it is missing the data for the other 17 rows. This is the create table command I was using before I uploaded the data:

```
CREATE TABLE Unavailability 
(Crew_ID varchar (8) NOT NULL,
Available text (3),
Licence_Number int (8),
CONSTRAINT pk11 primary key (Crew_ID));
```

Can someone please tell me what I can do to fix this as I want to prevent it happening to other tables as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crew_id field has a data length of 8 characters, yet every single value you provided in your example is 9 characters long. Try changing the length to 9, ie:

```
CREATE TABLE Unavailability 
(Crew_ID varchar (9) NOT NULL,
Available text (3),
Licence_Number int (8),
CONSTRAINT pk11 primary key (Crew_ID));
```

The inserts should otherwise be valid as you can see here -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/74544/1/0

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it worked. I am having trouble with another table for qualification however which is only outputting 2 records.         CREATE TABLE Qualification
(Licence_Number varchar (8) NOT NULL, 
Rank varchar (25),
CONSTRAINT pk 10 primary key (Licence_Number));          There are 20 records in total that I want to output but it only puts records 18 and 20

Comment: 1 Captain Licence
2 Captain Licence
3 First Officer Licence
4 First Officer Licence
5 Captain Licence
6 Captain Licence
7 First Officer Licence
8 First Officer Licence
9 Captain Licence
10 Captain Licence
11 First Officer Licence
12 First Officer Licence
13 Captain Licence
14 Captain Licence
15 First Officer Licence
16 First Officer Licence
17 Captain Licence
18 Captain Licence
19 First Officer Licence
20 First Officer Licence                                      That is the table which I have created in excel for the qualifications table creates by the above command.

Comment: @user3742254 can you create a new question with those details (formatted)? It's hard to tell where one value ends and another begins. But I would take a look at your constraints and make sure none are violated. Better yet, try running an insert statement (manually) for just one record that fails, and you'll probably have your answer as the error message should tell you why it fails.

Comment: Ok I will create a new question now, I'm going to try the insert too.

Comment: it only lets me ask once every 90 minutes so I will post it in 45 minutes or so. thanks

Comment: I have posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596771/csv-import-not-showing-all-row-data-on-phpmyadmin