# csv import not showing all row data on phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, excel, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a table which I made on excel in csv format to use on phpmyadmin sql for a university project. Most tables have been successful but some have had issues. I have made a table for a pilot qualification using the following create command:

```
CREATE TABLE Qualification
(Licence_Number int (8) NOT NULL, 
Rank varchar (25),
CONSTRAINT pk 10 primary key (Licence_Number));
```

This table has been successfully created. However, when I import the csv data, it does not import all of the 20 rows, merely row 18 and 20 but the go command gives the impression that it has. This is the table which I have created on excel:

```
1   Captain Licence
2   Captain Licence
3   First Officer Licence
4   First Officer Licence
5   Captain Licence
6   Captain Licence
7   First Officer Licence
8   First Officer Licence
9   Captain Licence
10  Captain Licence
11  First Officer Licence
12  First Officer Licence
13  Captain Licence
14  Captain Licence
15  First Officer Licence
16  First Officer Licence
17  Captain Licence
18  Captain Licence
19  First Officer Licence
20  First Officer Licence
```

On phpmyadmin however, it merely outputs this:

```
Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
18
Captain Licence

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
20
First Officer Licence
```

Once again, I have selected "replace all data" and left "columns enclosed with" blank. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would suggest that you manually input 2 rows of data into the database, then export the database to csv file. You can then be sure of what phpMyAdmin required format is. Follow the format, and i believe you should be fine.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work-it shows the format as 1;"Captain" and it shows it in only one column after being exported. I have also tried entering the 20 fields manually in sets of 2-the first 2 worked ok but after i tried entering 3, captain and 4, first officer it gives me this error and won't let me proceed-#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Captain' for key 'Rank'                             All I wanted to do for this table was to display what each licence number corresponded to in a rank, I have no idea why it has to be such an uphill struggle!